# WPF C# how to set the first window to be read only until I close the second one?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to set the first window to be read only until I close the second one?

In button click i open new Window

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    window2 win2 = new window2();
    win2.Show();
}
```

Now the first window should be read-only.

After closing the second window, the first one should have full access again

Comment: In order to get a general answer, you would have to explain what you mean by making a window "read only", but it sounds like what you're aiming for might simply be making `win2` a modal dialog, which you could achieve through calling `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`.

Comment: SchowDialog this is what I was looking for. Thank you fuglede